# How to login without password only login with lastname firstname and dateofbirth thorough auth using Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

How to login without password means using last name, first name, and date of birth using Laravel 5.2? Here I am having multiple authentication using email and password; the authentication is perfect if am using last name, first name, and date of birth, these fields am getting error:

> undefined index password.

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 1):

Though i feel it was insecure. I am giving the way to do this.

**Step 1 :**

Get the firstname, lastname and dob,

```
$userData['first_name'] = Input::get('first_name');
$userData['last_name'] = Input::get('last_name');
$userData['dob'] = Input::get('dob');
```

or

```
$userData = Input::except('_token');
```

**Step 2 :**

Validate the Input

```
$validation = Validator::make($userData, User::$login);

if ($validation->passes()) {
// Validation passed
}
else
{
// Validation Failed
}
```

**Step 3 :**

```
Get the user record

$user = User::where('first_name',  Input::get('first_name'))->where('last_name','!=',Input::('last_name'))->where('dob','!=',Input::('dob'))->first();
```

**Step 4 :**

Authenticate the user [manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users)

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user['id']);
```

Now you're done. You can redirect or send any message that is required.

**Note :**

You can change the field name according to your need.

Comment: thank you guys for your suggestions i solved my problem